# How does SKAction scaleBy:duration: method works under the hood?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sknode

Need to have a way to "scale by" without using an SKAction, but it should mimic changes to SKNode as `scaleBy:duration:` method does.

How does scale factor changes on the node which was "scaledBy"?

Comment: linear interpolation of the scale values from current value to current value + "by" value .. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation (link makes it look much more complicated than it is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there's some kind of action manager running its own `update:` method (like what `SKScene` has) and updates the appropriate properties (in this case `xScale` and `yScale`) of the node attached to the action on each callback.

The `update:` method takes an `NSTimeInterval` parameter that can be used to know how far along the animation to progress and when to finish.

**EDIT**

In cocos2d-x, the `CCScaleBy` action is a subclass of `CCScaleTo`. The update method goes something like this:

```
void CCScaleTo::update(float time)
{
    setScaleX(m_fStartScaleX + m_fDeltaX * time);
    setScaleY(m_fStartScaleY + m_fDeltaY * time);
}
```

Comment: If you want to see an implementation, check out cocos2d.

Comment: updated my question, I am interested in scale factor changes.

Comment: Again, check out cocos2d and see how they handle it.

Comment: I saw, but SKAction's duration I am using is 0.0. So just scaling to startScaleX + scaleBy is not working as expected.

Comment: What you're saying is that Apple's `[SKAction scaleBy:duration:]` doesn't work if you set duration to `0.0`?

Comment: It works, what I need to know is HOW does scale changes if duration of the action is 0.0.

Comment: That should be pretty obvious - it changes the value immediately. Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: The main question is HOW DOES IT CHANGE that scale values. Which formula?

Comment: I've updated my answer for you. It's a pretty straightforward algorithm. Again, if you want the details just look at the full cocos2d code, it's short and easy to follow.